# Installing sql server 2016 under windows 10 - language problems?

Tags: windows-10, installation, sql-server

I'm trying to install sql server 2016 under windows 10 (german). I tried both the english and the german version and also setting (windows settings) my region and language from german to english , but to no avail. I also tried to installi it with administration permissions.

I always get:

> This SQL Server setup media does not support the language of the OS or does not have the SQL Server English-language version installation files.......

The windows I ahve is a windows 8 -> windows 10 upgrade.

Now my question is: IS this really some sort of language problem, or is there something that is overlooked / done wrong there by me?

Comment: *The windows I ahve is a windows 8 -> windows 10 upgrade.*. This means, you have Windows 10, you don't need to indicate you upgraded from windows 8.1 (there is no difference between an upgraded installation of Windows 10 and a clean install of Windows 10)

Comment: @Ramhound at another questio when I had problems with windows 10 it was indicated that in some rare cases it CAN make a difference if its a clean install or an upgrade.

Comment: I don't know whom indicate that but the only difference is a single registry key value.

Comment: is your Win 10 home edition or Professional edition? and also what is the edition of your sql server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

[The cause](https://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting104.htm) of the error is that you are applying an English update on a SQL Server installed in German language.

**Use PowerShell to:**

1. Check your current language: `Get-WinUserLanguageList`
2. Set the language you want: `Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US`
3. Reboot and try to install

**Still doesn't work? Let's try to change [these 3 parameters](https://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting176.htm):**

1. `User interface settings:` In Control Panel, open Region and Language. On the Languages ​​tab, for Language used in menus and dialogs, select a value from the list. Click Apply to confirm the change and OK to close the window.
2. `User locale:` In Control Panel, open Regional and Language Options. On the Regional Options tab, for Select an item to display its settings, select a value from the list. Click Apply to confirm the change and OK to close the window.
3. `System locale:` In Control Panel, open Regional and Language Options. On the Advanced tab, for Select a language that matches the version of the non-Unicode programs you want to use, select a value from the list. Click Apply to confirm the change and OK to close the window.

**Still doesn't work? We need to use the hammer :(**

1. Delete the `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110` folder (110 for SQL Server 2012, 120 for SQL Server 2014and so on)
2. Try again.